# Create 20 seconds video from 600 png images in FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to Create a 20 seconds video from 600 png images in FFMPEG.

The issue is , it creates a 20 seconds video BUT , the 600 frames are about used 10 times and repeats very fast about more than 10 times in 20 seconds.

I'm using :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30000/1001 -i <input%d.png> <out.mp4>
```

Please Help ! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because you have 600 images for 20 seconds, you can simply set the frame rate on 30fps. Additionally you should use -r instead of -framerate

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i [sequence] -c:v libx264 [output]
```

`-c:v libx264` is simply the encoder used for the job.

You should also rename your images to something like this: img001.png, img002.png, img003.png. [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) is a fast way to do this. Change `[sequence]` to `img%03d.png`. If you want to use more than 3 digit's, change `%03d`.

Comment: The lack of zero-padding in the file name sequence is the culprit as you describe in the last paragraph. Why do you suggest `-r` instead of `-framerate`?

Comment: I always use -r, and tough that is was different from -framerate. But according the manual there's no difference for most input formats.

Comment: Where at in the manual does it claim there is no difference? There is a difference for image demuxing: see [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) on `-r` option. `-r` is less robust than `-framerate` and can result in dropped frames.